# Disabling the past dates

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to disable the past dates from the `laravel-backpack` component `date-range-picker`.

```
`$this->crud->addField([
  'name' => ['event_start_date', 'event_end_date'],
  'type' => 'date_range',
  'label' => "Start Date",
  'wrapperAttributes'=>['class'=>'form-group col-md-6'],
  'default' => [date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d")],
  'date_range_options' => [
     'todayBtn' => 'linked',
     'timePicker' => true,
     'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  ],
  'allows_null' => true,
]);`
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name' => ['event_start_date', 'event_end_date'],
            'type' => 'date_range',
            'label' => "Start Date",
            'wrapperAttributes'=>['class'=>'form-group col-md-6'],
            //'default' => [date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d")],
            'date_range_options' => [
                'todayBtn' => 'linked',
                // options sent to daterangepicker.js
                //'timePicker' => true,
                'startDate' => date("Y-m-d"),
                'endDate' => date("Y-m-d"),
                'minDate'=> date("Y-m-d"),
                'locale' => ['format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD']
            ],
            'allows_null' => true,
        ]);
```